# "Escape from New York" movie - title and tagline translation check

Tags: contemporary-latin, sentence-translation, translation-check

I have a "Escape from New York" movie poster over my desk.

It reads:

> **1997.
> New York City is a walled maximum security prison.
> Breaking
>   out is impossible.
> Breaking in is insane.**
>
> **ESCAPE FROM NEW YORK**

The Latin translation I made, just for the kicks:

> **MCMXCVII** (or maybe) **MMDCCL (Ab urbe condita)
> Civitas Novus Eboracus muratus maxima securitas carcer est.
> Erumpere est
>   impossibile.
> Irrumppere est insanum.**
>
> **EVADERE NOVO EBORACO**

Is that correct? I'm not sure about the second line (*Civitas Novus Eboracus...*) and if the use of the ablative case in the title is pertinent.

Also, there may be a better translation for "breaking in / out".

Comment: Something seems off to me about _maxima securitas_. I feel like it should be in a case other than nominative, perhaps the ablative, but I am not sure.

Comment: Just something? That whole phrase triggers all my dog Latin alarms.

Comment: Well, I mean, _muratus_ agrees with both _Novus Eboracus_ and _carcer_ so that's a bit confusing, and _Civitas_ doesn't agree gender-wise with _Novus Eboracus_, so I can see what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my offer for a translation:

> A. D. MCMXCVII
> Urbs Novum Eboracum carcer penitus munitus at maximae securitatis est.
> Fugere nequibis.
> Introrumpens insanies.
>
> Fuga Novo Eboraco

In modern context it is clear that the year means the typical modern years, not *ab urbe condita*; counting years *a.u.c.* would be confusing and hard to put in context, whereas 1997 immediately means something to most.
The abbreviation for *Anno Domini* is not absolutely necessary, but clears ambiguity — if there ever was any.

I am not sure if it is necessary to emphasize that it is the city instead of the state of New York.
If you want to make the distinction, I suggest *urbs*.
My first interpretation of *civitas* was that it meant state, but this is probably not what you wanted to say.

I wrote that the prison is "thoroughly fortified" (*penitus munitus*, where *penitus* is an adverb) and "of maximum security" (*maximae securitatis*).
The ablative of quality is a possible alternative for the genitive I chose, but I find the genitive somehow more natural here.

I took more liberty with the last two lines.
They say "You will not be able to escape" and "Breaking in, you will be insane".
I think these capture the spirit.
I could not find a neat impersonal way to phrase it as in English, so I put it in the second person singular.

The structure "infinitive *est* adjective" is possible, but I did not find an adjective for "impossible" that I would like.
If you want something with this structure, I recommend:

> Fugere est inane.
> Introrumpere est insanum.

While *erumpere* and *irrumpere* are possible, I think the message is clearer (but the comparison weaker) with *fugere* and *introrumpere*.
These seem to be less prone to misinterpretation, which is often an issue with prefixed verbs in Latin; also *evadere* can be misread all too easily.
*Introrumpere* means pretty narrowly "to break in" and *fugere* is "to escape".

For the title I chose the noun *fuga* for "escape".
At least I read the first word of "escape from New York" as a noun, not a verb.
If you want it to be a verb, an infinitive doesn't sound assertive enough for a title.
I would expect an imperative instead, but I find the noun most appropriate.
The plain ablative of separation without prepositions is what I expect for a city.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably say *civitas carcer maximus securitate*, using the ablative of respect. Using the nominative *securitas* is wrong. In English, the phrase “maximum security” is functioning as an adjective and properly should be hyphenated (“maximum-security prison”).

Don’t translate it word-for-word, but try to capture the *meaning* of the words.

Just saying.

Comment: Using the nominative _maximus_ is wrong. Just saying.

Comment: @SamK : Nope. It modifies *carcer*, so it is correct as written. The ablative qualifies the adjective (“a prison greatest with respect to security”). Just saying.

Comment: If you gonna keep saying "just saying", at least have the decency to say it in Latin. Just kidding (and saying).

Comment: @MPW Hmmm. I just totally missed the "ablative of respect" part. I was thinking more along the lines of _carcer maxima securitate_ otherwise. Your answer is also missing the "New York" part, which seems a bit integral to the translation of the poster. My comment was also about the tone of your answer, which is a bit off-putting. Just saying.

Comment: As @SamK mentions, the ablative of quality should have both the describing noun (*securitas*) and the adjective (*maximus*) in ablative: *carcer maxima securitate*. // I recently asked [how to say "just kidding" in Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/6364/79), but there are no answers yet.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta : The ablative is specification does not: *maior natu* (older); hence my *maximus securitate*

Comment: You are right! For some reason I was reading it as *ablativus qualitatis* which would be *carcer maxima securitate*, but *ablativus respectus* does indeed make sense as *carcer securitate maximus*. Perhaps I was puzzled by the word order. (Also @SamK)