# How to say that you were just kidding?

Tags: idiom, plautus

It is not unusual to attempt to say something humorous but it is mistaken for as serious statement.
In this situation I might say "Just kidding!", "I wasn't serious!", "it was a joke!", or something along those lines.
What would be an idiomatic way to say so in Latin?

I do not recall seeing such a phrase.
I assume this could be found in Plautus, but any kinds of suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Incidentally, this is the 2018th question on our site.

Comment: All the Latin dictionaries on the first page of Google results (AKA the Internet) translate **I'm just kidding** to **I'm iustus kidding**, no joke.

Comment: @Rodia The internet saddens me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not as succinct as 'Just kidding,' but I think that what Plautus uses at *Amphitruo* 919–920 has a nice ring to it:

> si quid dictum est per iocum,
>   non aequom est id te serio praevortier.
>
> If anything has been said in jest, it isn't fair for you to take it seriously.

Obviously, *te* could be changed to *vos* to suit the audience. Or you could shorten the whole thing to *dictum (est) per iocum*.

Alternatively, you can just say *lusi*. An example of this use of *ludere* is found in letter 1.11 of Pliny the Younger. After complaining that he hasn't received any letters from Fabius Justus for quite a while, Pliny asks that he write just to tell him that he has nothing to say, or even that he write simply *si vales, bene est; ego valeo*, which was traditionally used as the mere opening to letters. He then says, *ludere me putas? serio peto*, 'Do you think I'm joking? I'm asking in all seriousness.'

**Update:** Another possibility, also less succinct than the original English, is an adaptation of Pliny's whole *ludere me putas? serio peto* statement, producing something like *serio dicere me puta(ti)s? ludo*, or *serio dixisse me puta(ti)s? lusi*. For *serio dicere*, see, for example, Plautus, *Epidicus* 31:

> [EPIDICUS] serione dicis tu? [THESPRIO] serio, inquam: hostes habent.
>
> **Epidicus:** Are you speaking in earnest?
>   **Thesprio:** In earnest, I say: the enemy has them [the arms of Stratippocles].

And of course, this passage opens up further possibilities, such as *haud serio dixi* – you could even throw in an *edepol* or *mehercle* for good measure.

Comment: *Per iocum* is what I learned and it's very well attested, from the earliest writers down to Justinian's reign. Even Cicero uses it. It would be my go-to.